# How to divide my datetime data into series data along with its values in kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a dataset with date values and and its corresponding status values.

I want to generate missing date values by one hour along with its status values.

Is it possible to do in kusto.

[image: Data]

I have tried generating it with make-series but it's allowing only default values in output, but i need status value instead of default some constant value

Comment: Please see the Data to understand my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datatable(Time:timespan, Status:int)
[
    timespan(00:00), 4
   ,timespan(04:00), 2
   ,timespan(12:00), 4
   ,timespan(20:00), 2
]
| make-series take_any(Status) default=int(null) on Time step 1h
| mv-expand Time to typeof(timespan), series_fill_forward(Status) to typeof(int)
```

| Status | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 01:00:00 |
| 4 | 02:00:00 |
| 4 | 03:00:00 |
| 2 | 04:00:00 |
| 2 | 05:00:00 |
| 2 | 06:00:00 |
| 2 | 07:00:00 |
| 2 | 08:00:00 |
| 2 | 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 11:00:00 |
| 4 | 12:00:00 |
| 4 | 13:00:00 |
| 4 | 14:00:00 |
| 4 | 15:00:00 |
| 4 | 16:00:00 |
| 4 | 17:00:00 |
| 4 | 18:00:00 |
| 4 | 19:00:00 |
| 2 | 20:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22PTQqDMBCF94J3mGUCFqK4EnqKdleKpGRCQ2MiJrYVeviOBhVKMxCGb37eGyUjxc0iO5sOm0hf6KUr4ER8DI1xkefZJc%20A3lplQjRC8ALqhRc7rxOvfnhZ/e%20vxNZ/zbMPdPKBh4CDwQCR8la6iSUnHBRqOdp4JEvMjdZy8A5m1xAi9lDelw3PA75ptUqV6CFOPXrNVk1SSwKtNta22g8vOahNZB%20YL/8C8giwjx4BAAA=)

Comment: I am able to generate the series now, Thank you David. But first record of my actual data starts with 00:10:00 instead of 00:00:00. I have used 1m interval to generate the series. So the value representation gone wrong, as the output shows from 00:00:00. Can you help me how can i get the correct data

Comment: Please post another question for this.

Comment: i have posted another, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable(Time:timespan, Status:int)
[
    timespan(00:00), 4
   ,timespan(04:00), 2
   ,timespan(12:00), 4
   ,timespan(20:00), 2
]
| order by Time asc
| extend next_Time = coalesce(next(Time) - 1h, Time)
| mv-expand Time = range(Time, next_Time, 1h) to typeof(timespan)
| project-away next_Time
```

| Time | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 01:00:00 | 4 |
| 02:00:00 | 4 |
| 03:00:00 | 4 |
| 04:00:00 | 2 |
| 05:00:00 | 2 |
| 06:00:00 | 2 |
| 07:00:00 | 2 |
| 08:00:00 | 2 |
| 09:00:00 | 2 |
| 10:00:00 | 2 |
| 11:00:00 | 2 |
| 12:00:00 | 4 |
| 13:00:00 | 4 |
| 14:00:00 | 4 |
| 15:00:00 | 4 |
| 16:00:00 | 4 |
| 17:00:00 | 4 |
| 18:00:00 | 4 |
| 19:00:00 | 4 |
| 20:00:00 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22P0QrCIBSG7wd7h3Op4MCNXQ16irqLCKenWiwdarVBD5%2061iBS8MDn%20Y6/Sviw2x7Jrrth48PhBqEZbAO/u6bTnubZPs8grOWWcN5wThnUibOV1zOvfnhZ/e%20v%20Lf/kGcvMFahhXaCGAaEkxHi6FEr0KEeE9%20ANKJHJ5FEmJJTKKC8sCTSaN0eBY7hDQUfxwp9nn/J1lksSBS8AT8NaE5kSZZGDNZcUfpCPMW0Km8eIZ%20bMgEAAA==)